# what are "1LL" and "-1LL" in C++

Tags: c++

Can anyone please let me know what exactly 1LL and -1LL are? Here is the line in which they have been used:

```
#define All_In(G) (((G) == 64) ? (W64)(-1LL) : ((1LL << (G))-1LL))
```

Comment: Literal for `long long`.

Comment: So, this line means what? I still can not get its meaning!!

Comment: It's trying to minimize the chance that there will be an overflow.  Because `(1 << G)` will tend to overflow a lot sooner than `(1LL << G)`, because `1` is of type `int`, which is generally smaller than `long long`.

Comment: `1` is of type `int`. `1L` is of type `long int`. `1LL` is of type `long long` int (a type introduced to the C standard in 1999 and to the C++ standard in 2011, but commonly provided before that as an extension). The sizes of these types vary from one compiler to another, but `long long` is required to be at least 64 bits (though I've seen a *non-conforming* C compiler with a 32-bit `long long` type). Since shifts can be better behaved on unsigned types, I might have used `1ULL` rather than `1LL`.

Comment: Described how the macro works step by step

Comment: Other example for const literal typing: `1.0f`. So the number 1 has to be interpreted as a single precision floating point number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LL stands for LongLong, which means at least 64-bit

Comment: It doesn't "mean 64 bits", though. It just means "long long".

Comment: Though it does imply(or rather, require) *at least* 64 bits.

Comment: (further to Benjamin's comment, see pages 21 & 22 of the C99 spec: "...  implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign. ... minimum value for an object of type long long int
`LLONG_MIN -9223372036854775807//−(2^63−1)`)"

Comment: Can anyone please translate what exactly the code line means? Because I still do not get it!!!

Comment: @user2517676: Then you should ask about the line of code (in your question), not just `LL`.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of the macro appears to be to produce an integer with the `G` least significant bits set.  `All_In(1)==1`, `All_In(2)==3`, `All_In(3)==7`, and so on.

In psuedo-code, the macro is saying this:

```
if G == 64
    produce -1
else
    produce (1 bitshifted left by G) - 1
```

[bit shifting, if you don't know what that is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift)

Comment: … but it produces integer overflow for G = 63. To correct, the literal should be `ull`, which makes the whole exercise a bit ironic.

Answer (score 3):

`LL` suffix of a constant literal means that the literal's type need to be interpreted as long long (signed). To answer exactly the question title: `1LL` is a constant literal, which value is `1` and it's type is long long. Similarly, `-1LL` is `-1` with the type long long.

You cannot pass `1LL` literal simply into functions which accept integer values of smaller types like long, short. Probably where the All_In macro is used the expected parameter is long long.

```
All_In(1)  == 0b00000000...00000001LL
All_In(2)  == 0b00000000...00000011LL
All_In(3)  == 0b00000000...00000111LL
All_In(4)  == 0b00000000...00001111LL
All_In(5)  == 0b00000000...00011111LL
All_In(6)  == 0b00000000...00111111LL
All_In(7)  == 0b00000000...01111111LL
All_In(8)  == 0b00000000...11111111LL
...
All_In(57) == 0b00000001...11111111LL
All_In(58) == 0b00000011...11111111LL
All_In(59) == 0b00000111...11111111LL
All_In(60) == 0b00001111...11111111LL
All_In(61) == 0b00011111...11111111LL
All_In(62) == 0b00111111...11111111LL
All_In(63) == 0b01111111...11111111LL
All_In(64) == 0b11111111...11111111LL
```

The macro works this way:

1. If the input parameter is 64 (`(G) == 64)` ? see ternary operator `?:`), then it yields a number which binary representation is 64 `1` (`(W64)(-1LL)`, where `W64` specifies that the width of the number is 64 in bits). For this you need to know, that in case of signed integers and in 2 complement number representation the -1 means all bits set to 1. For example in case of a signed char, the values range from -128 to 127. The binary representation of the -128 is `11111111`. Extend this to 64 bit length.
2. If the input is not 64, then it yields a number which has as many 1s in the binary representation as it is specified: `1LL << (G))-1LL`. This goes the following way, let's do it for input 3 and if the bit length is 8.

a. First it shifts the 1 by 3.

```
0b00000001 (2^0)
0b00000010 (2^1 after shifting by 1)
0b00000100 (2^2 after shifting by 1 again)
0b00001000 (2^3 after shifting by 1 again, 3 times all together)
```

b. Then it subtracts 1 from that number. This results in a number we wanted. 2^n-1 always consists of bits of ones without a zero in between them. So 2^3-1=7. Which representation is:

```
0b00000111
```

Probably this can be used to mask some flags or something.

*Note, that (`0b` prefix for representing binary literals in my example doesn't work with all C compilers).*

Answer (score 2):

The line of code is a macro that produces from a positive integer less than or equal to 64 a `long long` with that many `1`s in its binary expansion.  `AllIn(G)` equals $2^G - 1$.  Darn it, no TeX.  So,

```
AllIn(1)  == 0x0000000000000001LL
AllIn(2)  == 0x0000000000000003LL
AllIn(3)  == 0x0000000000000007LL
AllIn(4)  == 0x000000000000000FLL
AllIn(5)  == 0x0000000000000011LL
...
AllIn(64) == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFLL
```

Comment: `AllIn(63)` results in undefined behavior; It shifts into the sign bit and then it does `LLONG_MIN-1`. Assuming, of course, that `long long` is 64 bits.

Comment: The shift gives `0x8000000000000000`, and subtracting `1` gives `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, assuming a little-endian system.  Whether `long long` is 64 bits, or more, doesn't really matter.  Still, the macro should have used `LLU` instead.  Are there any sign-magnitude systems left?

Comment: if `0x8000000000000000` is out of range for signed long long (and it is for a 64 bit long long) then it's UB to create it from one like that.

Comment: 16 hex digits is 64 bits.

Comment: `1LL << 63` is equal to 2^63. `LLONG_MAX` is (2^63)-1, therefore 2^63 overflows `long long`'s range and `1LL << 63` is undefined behavior. Then, assuming the implementation produces the value LLONG_MIN, the macro does `LLONG_MIN - 1` which would again be undefined behavior.

Comment: By the way, this is not in criticism of your answer; I just happened to observe this fact while reading your answer.